# Why are Geralt's clothes and armour resetting back to the defaults?

Tags: the-witcher-2

As I progress through the game, I've been upgrading Geralt's armour and weaponry. When the game loads the next phase or chapter, all my weapons and armour are lost and it defaults back to Geralt's original uniform and weapon. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug, but it should only happen around three times, in the Prologue after the various conversations with Roche. The armour resets, and if you've applied any enhancements, they're back in your inventory. I think it's because the game was designed initially not to need you to do all sections of the prologue, and it didn't check.